# How to sync offline IndexedDB database with online oracle database when internet goes online in Laravel and vuejs

Tags: php, laravel, oracle, vuejs2

I am making inventory software and I am using Vuejs 2 as frontend and Laravel as backend.

I am using my oracle database as online remote database and IndexedDB database as offline database.

I am trying to make my software work offline and user can make Products and Invoices offline.

**I am trying to make when user make products or invoices offline it will store in IndexedDB and When Internet is goes online the products and invoices table store in IndexedDB sync with online oracle database.**

**My Question is: How to sync offline IndexedDB database with online oracle database when internet goes online in Laravel and vuejs.**

Comment: I guess you would need to check on page load if there is data in the indexedDB. if there is you will need to perform a request to the server. My question is how they are going to access the products and invoices if your site is offline? Do you build an additional app?

Comment: I am using vue js and add vue pwa package so it work offline. Now my app is Progressive Web Applications (PWA) and it work offline.

Comment: checkout this article https://medium.com/simplejs/how-to-enable-offline-detection-using-simple-browser-apis-398b4989605a

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai The offline and online events not work if i unplug internet cable or disconnect WIFI. offline and online events only work if i change throttling in network tab of Chrome Devtool.